# Best way to design React.js components without CSS

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs

I'm building a library of my components with React.js. For some reasons I don't want to use CSS for styling. Instead of it, I'm using JSON notation style, like

```js
{
  "some-class": {
    "color": "#755755"
  },

  "some-class:hover": {
    "background": "#CCC"
  }
}
```

By deisgn, React recommends keep components as stateless as possible, but for such conditions as `:hover` or `:active` I use `onMouseOver` and `onMouseOut`:

```js
/**
 * Mouse over handler
 * @return {Void}
 */
onMouseOver: function() {
    this.setState({
        style: extend(
            {}, 
            this.state.style, 
            style['mdui-btn-' + this.props.type + ':hover']
        )
    });
},

/**
 * Mouse out handler
 * @return {Void}
 */
onMouseOut: function() {
    this.setState({
        style: this.computeStyle()
    });
},
```

I assume that if I want to avoid using CSS I could use this behaviour. Is it a bad idea or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find this to be a clean way to handle hover style changes for a component:

```
var SomeComponent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {hovered: false};
  },
  toggleHovered: function(){
    this.setState({hovered: !this.state.hovered});
  }
  render: function(){
    //example for rendering a span with desired hovering functionality
    return(
      <span style={this.state.hovered ? myStyles.hoverOn : myStyles.hoverOff} onMouseOver={this.toggleHovered}> onMouseOut={this.toggleHovered}> 
        Some content 
      </span>
    );
  }
});

var myStyles = {
  hoverOn: {
    // whatever styles you want on hover
  },
  hoverOff: {
    // style for no hover
  }
};
```

Comment: Yeah, also could be an option. But what do you think about storing :hover in the state? I'm just thinking isn't it wrong by react design?

Comment: I don't see any problem with it.  Changing state will cause the component to re-render, which is the desired behavior.  To me it seems pretty common practice to store booleans in state that respond to user actions and trigger re-rendering.  Anything in particular you are worried about?

Comment: No, it's more about how to make it properly. Using CSS can help us avoid onMouseOver(Out) code and changing the state, but at the same moment it means, that you need to mess up with CSS code and it's issues.

Comment: Yeah, it really depends on the needs of your project.  This presentation is very informative in terms of using CSS vs JS styles: (https://speakerdeck.com/vjeux/react-css-in-js).   It is fine to use CSS, but if you want to do everything within reactjs, modifying state is the way to do it.   See this presentation on handling CSS tasks in JS: (https://speakerdeck.com/vjeux/react-css-in-js-react-france-meetup).